# Combine two sql server queries in one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to combine these 2 selects in one

```
 SELECT TOP 5 Sum([NumOfChats]) AS [NumOfChats]
            ,[CaseTypeName]
            ,[CaseSubTypeName]
      FROM #Result2
      GROUP BY [CaseTypeName]
            ,[CaseSubTypeName]

      SELECT Sum([NumOfChats]) AS [TotalNumOfChats]           
      FROM #Result2
```

First query sumerize top 5 NumOfChats and the second one all NumOfChats.

So i want to get in the same row for example:
5, Some_CaseTypeName, Some_CaseSubTypeName, 10(this is the total num of chats)

Comment: FYI `TOP` with no `ORDER BY` gives no guarantees of the output order.

Answer (score 2):

Use UNION ALL, select NULL in second query to get same number of columns as in first query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Sum([NumOfChats]) AS [NumOfChats]
            ,[CaseTypeName]
            ,[CaseSubTypeName]
      FROM #Result2
      GROUP BY [CaseTypeName]
            ,[CaseSubTypeName]
UNION ALL
      SELECT Sum([NumOfChats]) AS [TotalNumOfChats], NULL, NULL           
      FROM #Result2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T int = (SELECT Sum([NumOfChats])   
      FROM #Result2 )

  SELECT TOP 5 Sum([NumOfChats]) AS [NumOfChats]
        ,[CaseTypeName]
        ,[CaseSubTypeName]
        ,@T [TotalNumOfChats]    
  FROM #Result2
  GROUP BY [CaseTypeName]
        ,[CaseSubTypeName]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well